# prove continuity in the origin of $f(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have this function:
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{|x|^\alpha y}{|x|+y^2}&(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\
0&(x,y)=(0,0).
\end{cases}
$$

I prove f is continuous in the origin for $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$.
To prove f isn't continuous for $\alpha \le \frac{1}{2}$ which directions can i take?

Answer (score 0):

Put $y=|x|^{\alpha}$ giving you $$\frac{|x|^{2\alpha}}{|x| + |x|^{2\alpha}} = \frac{1}{|x|^{1-2\alpha} + 1} $$

If $\alpha \leq \frac{1}{2}$, $1 - 2\alpha \geq 0$ which implies the fraction tends to $1$ as $x \to 0$.

Hence, if $\alpha \leq \frac{1}{2}$, the limits across the paths $y=0$ and $y={|x|}^{\alpha}$ do not agree, which demonstrates discontinuity at the origin.